# JSP Pages cannot connect to MySQL Datasource via JBoss

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, web-applications, jboss

I am using Eclipse to create a simple project using JSP pages that pulls data from a MySQL database through a JBoss 6 AS.  It would appear I have the MySQL database properly bound to JBoss because it starts up without an errors and even displays the following message.

```
17:09:43,782 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/MyDatabase]
```

However when I try to launch my index.jsp page I get the following error:

```
exception 


javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get 
connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
jdbc/MyDatabase"


org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:862)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:791)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:112)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)


root cause 

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid:   "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc/MyDatabase"
  org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.getConnection(QueryTagSupport.java:318)
org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.doStartTag(QueryTagSupport.java:201)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_sql_005fquery_005f0(index_jsp.java:133)
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:64)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

I cannot seem to figure out why the last step of this whole thing, to allow my JSP page to be able to read from the DB is not working.

Files for reference:

**JBoss Standalone.xml**

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.1">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MyDatabase" pool-name="MyDatabase" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDatabase</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>root</user-name>
                    <password>root</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

**The Module.xml file located in JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/mysql/main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">
<resources>
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

Inside of JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/mysql/main I have the mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar

**Web.xml Contents**

```
 <display-name>TicketApp</display-name>

 <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>response.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
```

**Jboss-Web.xml Contents**

```
 Blank for now
```

**It also appears that when I add in resource-ref tags to both the web.xml and jboss-web.xml file that everything blows up and I get the following errors from JBoss:**

```
17:18:29,519 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1)       JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "MyApp.war"
17:18:29,994 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-11) MSC000001:        Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."MyApp.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service     jboss.deployment.unit."MyApp.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "MyApp.war"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:123) [jboss-as-server-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.GA-redhat-2]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)      [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011033: Could not load javax.sql.Datasource referenced in env-entry
at      org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ResourceReferenceProcessor.getResourceRefEntries(ResourceReferenceProcessor.java:159)
at    org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ResourceReferenceProcessor.processDescriptorEntries(ResourceReferenceProcessor.java:73)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.AbstractDeploymentDescriptorBindingsProcessor.deploy(AbstractDeploymentDescriptorBindingsProcessor.java:100)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:116) [jboss-as-server-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
... 5 more
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.sql.Datasource from [Module "deployment.TicketApp.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.3.GA-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ResourceReferenceProcessor.getResourceRefEntries(ResourceReferenceProcessor.java:157)
... 8 more

   17:18:30,009 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "MyApp.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"MyApp.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"MyApp.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"MyApp.war\"
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011033: Could not load javax.sql.Datasource referenced in env-entry
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.sql.Datasource from [Module \"deployment.MyApp.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
 17:18:30,014 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment MyApp.war in 7ms
 17:18:30,019 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"MyApp.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"MyApp.war\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"MyApp.war\"
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011033: Could not load javax.sql.Datasource referenced in env-entry
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.sql.Datasource from [Module \"deployment.MyApp.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}}}
```

Comment: '<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/MyDatabase</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.Datasource</res-type>
        <jndi-name>java:jboss/datasources/MyDatabase</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>'

This is what I tried to add to both jboss-web.xml and web.xml that caused the very last jboss errors.

Answer (score 0):

ClassNotFoundException suggests to me that JBOSS isn't finding your MySQL JDBC driver classes.

Put the JARs in the JBOSS server /lib folder and see if that helps.

Update: Here's the pertinent line in the stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.sql.Datasource
```

[findjar.com](http://www.findjar.com/class/javax/sql/DataSource.html) says it should be ni one of these jars.  Find it.

Comment: I put the MySQL Connector Jar inside of the lib folder and I got the same response